# Unsupported attribute in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am receiving the below error in the module.tf. This module.tf pass the vpc_id as the input variable to another module(api_gateway).

│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on modules.tf line 47, in module "gw":
│   47:   vpc_id          = module.net.vpcs.inspire.id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.net is object with 1 attribute "cert_arn"
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "vpcs".

```
module "gw" {
  source = "./api_gateway"

  vpc_id          = module.net.vpcs.inspire.id
  subnets         = module.net.subnets
  security_groups = module.net.sg
  dns             = module.net.dns
}
```

In "net" folder we have the below tf files (vpc.tf and output.tf).

```
vpc.tf
=======
resource "aws_vpc" "inspire" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    Name = "VPC"
  }
}

output.tf
=========
output "vpcs" {
  value = {
    "inspire": aws_vpc.inspire,
  }
}

output "subnets" {
  value = {
    "public": [aws_subnet.public-a, aws_subnet.public-b],
    "private": [aws_subnet.private-a, aws_subnet.private-b],
  }
}

output "sg" {
  value = {
    "vpc_internal": aws_security_group.vpc_internal,
    "public_egress": aws_security_group.public_egress,
    "public_http_ingress": aws_security_group.public_http_ingress,
    "public_https_ingress": aws_security_group.public_https_ingress,
  }
}

output "dns" {
  value = {
    "private": aws_route53_zone.private,
    "public": aws_route53_zone.public
  }
}

output "cert_arn" {
  value = var.certify_domain ? aws_acm_certificate_validation.elb_cert[0].certificate_arn : ""
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you have? Because the error says there is only one output and it does not seem it is the one you want, rather `module.net is object with 1 attribute "cert_arn"`.

Comment: @MarkoE, there is one for subnets, sg and dns and after that we have output.tf (updated my query for your reference)

output "vpcs" {
  value = {
    "inspire": aws_vpc.inspire,
  }
}
.....
......
output "cert_arn" {
  value = var.certify_domain ? aws_acm_certificate_validation.elb_cert[0].certificate_arn : ""
}

Comment: Please add all the **relevant** code to the question.

Comment: Are you expecting to have more than one VPC ID? Additionally, why do you want the output to be a map instead of just exporting the attribute you need/want?

Comment: Thanks @Marko E for your reply. There are many modules used for this terraform requirement. I am sharing only the gist of it. We are using the map(any) for VPC because there is few modules (ecs) using the vpcs, subnets, sg, and cert_arn apart from api_gateway 

module.tf (which also has api_gateway (alias gw) pls, refer above)
========

module "ecs" {
  source = "./ecs"
  vpcs            = module.net.vpcs
  subnets         = module.net.subnets
  security_groups = module.net.sg
  dns             = module.net.dns
  cert_arn        = module.net.cert_arn
}

Comment: @MarkoE et all, Any help on this issue please?

Comment: I don't see where the issue is unless you haven't posted the last version of your code and tried with that. The error from the question means you are doing something wrong, either the output value was messed up or you are doing something else which is not clear from the code you added to the question.